# Syntax error while trying to get CPU Usage

Tags: php

I would like to get **CPU** usage using shell_exec but i'm getting syntax error, this is my code:

```
$cpu_usage = " top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}' ";
shell_exec($cpu_usage);
```

Error :

**syntax error, unexpected 's' (T_STRING)**

Comment: Can you print out the contents of `$cpu_usage` after you set it? Also, what exactly is the error you receive?

Comment: @JohnGlenn  updated please double check :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: You need to escape certain characters in your command -- `" top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)"` for example should be `" top -bn1 | grep \"Cpu(s)\" `

Comment: @marco-a  yes exactly, which one :) ?

Comment: @ElYousfiRachid I'd use a nowdoc string here, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error message because you (unintentionally) terminate the string too early:

```
$cpu_usage = " top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}' ";
//                             ^ PHP sees this as the end of the string
```

The most painless way of solving this would be to use [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) string notation, as it doesn't do any parsing inside the string:

> Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, **but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc**. The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text **without the need for escaping**.

(emphasis mine)

```
$cpu_usage = <<<'STR'
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'
STR;

shell_exec($cpu_usage);
```